# Is it possible to suppress all naming errors from FxCop for a specific class?

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop

Due to reasons beyond my control (them being a DB of another system whose members follow different naming conventions) I have to make a class with a dozen of members that each fail 3 to 4 naming rules each, not to mention methods, which also take parameters that break the same rules. As such this results in about 80 pointless and annoying warnings.

Is there any way (short of [GeneratedCodeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.generatedcodeattribute.aspx)) to suppress them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the [GeneratedCodeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.generatedcodeattribute.aspx) is the only way to automatically suppress an entire class.

Comment: @Vilx Sadly it is sealed as well so you can't even inherit to create a class with a better name for the context.